# Android Build process: using aapt on Resource files?

Tags: java, android

I am unsure about the following information from [this link](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2010/06/07/understanding-the-android-build-process/) that details the Android Build Process.

I am basically wondering why the resource files need to be cnverted to Java source files (first step), then also packaged up to a .ap_ file?

What is the difference between the two steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the resource files need to be cnverted to Java source files

They are not being "cnverted to Java source files". A Java source file -- `R.java` -- is built using the data from the resources, and that file represents a listing of all of the available resources. This file provides constants for Android app developers to use to refer to these resources from the rest of their Java code.

To draw an analogy, the Web is not "cnverted" to Google's search engine; Google's search engine represents an index of the Web. Similarly, resources are not "cnverted to Java source files" like `R.java`; `R.java` represents an index of the resources.

Comment: Thanks, so what is the difference between the two steps? I.e. Resource code generation and packaging of non compiled resources

Comment: @user4125772: Those steps have nothing to do with each other, beyond sharing a common utility (**`aapt`**) and using resources as input.